# Can't pass 1d array into a method because there is a 2d array parameter

Tags: java, arrays, types, incomplete-type, 2048

I can't pass the 1d array into the method because there is a 2d array parameter. I can't remove the 2d array parameter because my 2048 game board runs on that 2d array board subject. Is there a workaround? I want the `slideUp` to work on *temp* and still keep my 2d array parameter *board*.

```java
public void slideUp(int[][] board) {
    for (int column = 0; column < board[0].length; column++) {
        int[] temp = getCol(board, column);
        slideUp(temp);
        for (int i = 0; i < board[0].length; i++) {
            board[i][column] = temp[i];
        }
    }
}
```

> Error code: incompatible types: int[] cannot be converted to int[][] slideUp(temp);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a workaround, you can create a new method that accepts `int[]`, then represent a *1d array* as a *2d array* of a single row, and call the old method, something like this:

```java
public void callSlideUp(int[] row) {
    // a 2d array of a single row
    slideUp(new int[][]{row});
}

public void slideUp(int[][] board) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could overload the method by creating another method with the same name, but using a 1d array as a parameter.

```
public void slideUp(int[] board) {
    //your code here
}
```

You would have to change this to handle a 1d array.

```
 board[i][column]
```